# Capture HTTP/S calls from HTML/JavaScript programmatically

Tags: http, ssl, urllib2, python-requests

Taking some basic HTML and JavaScript e.g.

```
<img src="http://example.com?a=1" />
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://example.net/script.js"
</script>
```

There are definitely 2 HTTP requests made, one for an img (`example.com?a=1`) and another for some JavaScript (`example.net/script.js`).

However, `example.net/script.js` may return some JavaScript which makes another request:

```
document.write("<script src='http://example.org/script.js'></script>")
```

This would result in a third http request to http://example.org/script.js.

A rather naive attempt to do this in Python looked like:

1. Extract all URLs in original HTML/JavaScript.
2. For each URL, open using urllib2.urlopen(url)
3. Check response for further URLs and open using urllib2.urlopen(url)

Of course, this doesn't allow for JavaScript which, only once rendered, constructs a valid URL and makes the HTTP request.

I then considered some kind of webkit engine to first render the response of each HTTP request, pull out the URLs and open using `urllib2.urlopen(url)`.

This seemed non-trivial and complex. Is there an easier way?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? If you just want to make software that logs every request made by a page, then your webkit approach is the correct one; take a look at Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: @André Daniel - Selenium WebDriver looks great. I see it has Python bindings too. I've got a basic demo working (after downloading the driver binary). However there are two shortfalls: 1) It doesn't appear to providing a way of logging all HTTP/S requests and 2) It can execute JavaScript, or 'get' a URL, but I can't find a way to execute combined HTML / JavaScript 'code snippet'

Comment: It's a browser, so obviously it isn't designed to execute arbitrary JS and HTML on the fly... you can try setting up a lightweight web server, using Python to generate a complete page combining your JS and HTML and finally pointing the webdriver to that page hosted on that server.

Comment: @André Daniel - I can see that working. Thank you. Do you have any ideas on achieving logging ot HTTP/S requests?

Comment: Check this out : http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/is-there-a-capturenetworktraffic-implementation-in-selenium-2-via-webdriver